# Is there a Python analogue to Julia's LaTeXStrings?

Tags: python, latex, escaping, julia, tex

In Julia there is a package [LaTeXStrings](https://github.com/stevengj/LaTeXStrings.jl) that allows for convenient input of LaTeX strings. E.g. you don't have to treat `\` as an escape character or `$` as a special symbol:

```
L"an equation: $1 + \alpha^2$"
```

instead of

```
"an equation: \$1 + \\alpha^2\$"
```

Is there an analogue in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to LaTeX, but you could use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which are marked by the letter `r` or `R` prefixing the string, as in `r"your string"`.

For example:

```
>>> s = r"an equation: $1 + \alpha^2$"
>>> print(s)
an equation: $1 + \alpha^2$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Sympy might be what you're looking for. It's a symbolic mathematics library which supports Latex:

```
>>> from sympy import init_printing
>>> from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
>>> init_printing()
>>> expr1 = parse_latex("\int_{a}^{b} x^2 dx")
>>> expr1
prints the integral in ascii in console or Latex in IPython QTConsole
```

This requires an additional dependency of the antlr-python-runtime library, which can be installed via conda/pip.